# Directory write permissions check

Tags: c#, security, file-system

Consider the following method that I have for checking write permissions on a directory path:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check existence and write permissions of supplied directory.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="directory">The directory to check.</param>
protected static void CheckPermissions(string directory)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(String.Format(JobItemsStrings.Job_DirectoryNotFound, directory));
    }

    // Check permissions exist to write to the directory.
    // Will throw a System.Security.SecurityException if the demand fails.
    FileIOPermission ioPermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, directory);
    ioPermission.Demand();
}
```

When running FxCop, this code throws up a **"CA2103 - Review imperative security"** warning, albeit with a certainty of 25%, with this info:

> "Use of imperative demands can lead to
>   unforeseen security problems. The
>   values used to construct a permission
>   should not change within the scope of
>   the demand call. For some components
>   the scope spans from the demand call
>   to end of the method; for others it
>   spans from the demand call until the
>   component is finalized. If the values
>   used to construct the permission are
>   fields or properties, they can be
>   changed within the scope of the demand
>   call. This can lead to race
>   conditions, mutable read-only arrays,
>   and problems with boxed  value types."

Bascially, is FxCop being over-cautious, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for StackOverflow based on the FAQs guidelines for what is an applicable question.

Comment: @Mark: Hmm, well the FAQ says "If you are looking for specific feedback about… Code correctness, ..., Security issues in a code snippet, etc … then you are in the right place!" I figured my question was a pretty good fit for that. But, if it is felt that it better suited for SO, then fair enough. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This FxCop warning is basically asking you to make sure ("Review") that that non-constant you are passing (`directory`) to the security permission does not change while the permission is in effect.  Basically, FxCop isn't sure if it is possible for the code (or some rogue module that a hacker has put in place) to do something like the following:

1. Set `directory` to "c:\Temp\"
2. `.Demand()`
3. `<untrusted>`**Set `directory` to "c:\Windows\System32\"**`</untrusted>`
4. Write something into a file contained in `directory`.

In this particular case, since `directory` is a non-ref parameter, it is not possible for another module outside your call-descendants to modify it.  Thus, what you need to check for:

- Anything in this method assigning a value to `directory`
- Anything in this method that passes `directory` by reference (`ref`/`out`/unsafe pointers)

*Disclaimer: I am not a code security expert and have no formal training as such.  I may have missed entire classes of things to look for here. If you are dealing with code that has real-world security implications, I highly suggest you hire a consultant who does, rather than take what I wrote above as gospel.*

Comment: Thanks, you have clarified what I thought. This does not have Earth-shattering implications - I just want to gracefully handle any circumstance where the permissions don't allow writing by popping a MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

When working with files, checking before an operation can be  useful, but you still always need to handle relevant exceptions (e.g. `FileNotFoundException`, `IOException`).

The permissions (or existence) of a file/directory may change between the time you check and time the operation is invoked (`new FileIOPermission(...)` in this case). This situation is more common than it seems.